# new Date() не обновляет значения

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, localstorage

Почему new Date возвращает одни и те же значения(одно и тоже время)?
Нужно чтоб при добавление сообщения ему возвращалась соответствующие время(при котором он был добавлен).
В коде ниже выводятся сообщения с одним и тем же значением времени, пока страницу не перезагрузишь.

В чем дело? я что то не так сделал или так и должно быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var time = new Date();
var timeS = time.toISOString();

$("#add-text").click( function() {

  var message = $("#text").val();

  $("#chat").append("<p><time class='timeago' datetime=" + timeS + ">" + timeS + "</time> " + message + "</p>");

  $("#form")[0].reset();

  var chat = $("#chat").html();
  localStorage.setItem("chat", chat);
  return false;
});

if(localStorage.getItem("chat")) {
  $("#chat").html(localStorage.getItem("chat"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <form id="form" action="#" method="POST">
    <textarea id="text" placeholder="Введите текст сообщения" rows="3" cols="40" style="vertical-align: top;"></textarea>
    <input id="add-text" type="submit" value="Добавить запись" style="vertical-align: middle;">
  </form>

  <div id="chat"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявляйте время при клике

```
$('#add-text').click(function(){
   var time = new Date();
   var timeS = time.toISOString();
   /*Далее ваш код*/
})
```

Answer (score 1):

у тебя уже получается сначала дата создается и присваивается в момент инициализации переменной

> var time = new Date();
>    var timeS = time.toISOString();

и его ты уже используешь
Если я правильно понял то тебе надо инициализировать переменную в момент вызова этой переменой. Как показал @DarkSir при клике